# Linq dynamic order query result by typed input string

Tags: linq

I must use Dynamic Linq because the table dynamically changes upon user's geolocation.
There's an autocompletion text input box passing the typed-in string to the controller.

I just want the output matching list to be ordered by the input string, i.e. if I start typing "bo" i want "**Bo**rdeaux" to appear before "Stras**bo**urg".
Here's the relevant code:

```
 public JsonResult GetTags(string term)
    {
        string countryCode = "FR"; // this is really picked up dynamically
        string GeoData = "Models.GeoData_" + countryCode;
        var searchResult = db.Set(GeoData)
        .AsQueryable()
        .Where("PlaceName.Contains(@0)", term)
        .Select("new (PlaceName, PostalCode, Latitude, Longitude, ID AS GeoDataID)")
        .OrderBy(?????);
```

Comment: Why dont you `Order By PlaceName ASC`? that should work, i guess

Comment: Or Sort the response before sending it back.

Comment: Try OrderBy(r=> r.PlaceName.IndexOf(term))

Comment: Jianping. That's what I was used to do before having to switch to dynamic tables but you cannot with dynamic linq; no lambda here.

Comment: TheUnknown: ordering by PlaceName is not a solution. You type "bo" and you get any "abo" first. Sorting the response? Sure: can you show how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was "Contains" returns all results... *containing* the input string while I really need only those starting with it.
So the solution was substituting 'Contains' with 'StartsWith'. 
Once that has been fixed, now it makes sense to order all placenames 'starting with *term*' alphabetically.

```
public JsonResult GetTags(string term)
{
    string countryCode = "FR"; // this is really picked up dynamically
    string GeoData = "Models.GeoData_" + countryCode;
    var searchResult = db.Set(GeoData)
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where("PlaceName.StartsWith(@0)", term)
    .OrderBy("PlaceName")
    .Select("new (PlaceName, PostalCode, Latitude, Longitude, ID AS GeoDataID)")
```

Also do not forget to set jQuery autocomplete parameter

```
sortResults: false
```